# need a nsdictionary with same key values

Tags: xcode, list, nsdictionary

i need a nsdictionary or other type of list to have multiple values with same keys like this:

```
tag = asfsdf;
tag = sdfsd;
tag = werwe;
```

cuz i have to send them to a webservice, and the webservices only accepts tags  like this:

```
  "tags" : [
    "tag":fews",
    "tag":"df"
  ]
```

with a array after jsonserialization i guet:

```
  "tags" : [
    "tag = fews",
    "tag = df"
  ]
```

doesnt work, cant change the webservice.
anyone has any idea? ndsdictionary cant have the same key values.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to just create 2 `NSArray` objects; call one 'keys' and the other 'values'. As long as you aren't doing a lot of adds and removes from the middle of the arrays it should be straight forward.

The other/better option (which I figure you've already dismissed) is to use an `NSDictionary`, but the "value" of each key is actually an `NSArray`. When you need to spit out the contents you'd just use the same key value for each item in the array.